# Retrieve all tables from sql-alchemy in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to get all the tables from the database whose `Account=='Given Account'`. But I wasn't able to fetch all the tables, only one table is getting fetched. Please help! Thank you!

```
    @app.route('/user_account/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def user_account():
         account = session['id']
         transactions = Transaction.query.filter_by(Account=account).all()
         return render_template('user_account.html',transactions=transactions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `Transaction` model object which will only give you results from the transactions table. If you are looking to return all tables the account is associated with you will need to import and call each object. For example:

```
orders = Order.query.filter_by(Account=account).all()
```

This would return all rows of orders that are associated with the account being queried. However this assumes you've set up your database model with [relationship configurations.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationships.html) Ie your transaction model refers to the account being queried by with `ForeignKey` or `Relationship`:

```
class Transaction(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Relationships.
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id',
                                                  onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                  ondelete='CASCADE'),
                        index=True, nullable=False)
```